# Finite Interval under Nonnegative Real Numbers

Tags: real-numbers

I want to construct a generic finite interval under $\mathbb{R_+}$ - it should be bounded, closed and it should include $0$ as the lower bound. This would allow me to choose an element from this compact set (i.e. $ x \in [0, b] \subset R_+$ where b is a finite number) . I cannot do this with $\mathbb{R_+}$ because it is not bounded. How can I represent this interval?

I was looking at a text on Lebesgue outer measure and I found the following definition:

We define the $\text{Lebesgue outer measure}$ of a set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ by

$\lambda^*(A)$ = inf $\lbrace \sum_{j=1}^\infty |I_j|: A \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty I_j$ where $I_j$ are bounded intervals $\rbrace$

They note that for a finite sum, $\lambda^*(A)$ is a (finite) nonnegative real number.

I guess I can use this. Any comments?

Comment: A finite interval that contains all nonnegative real numbers?

Comment: @Eff  the set of nonnegative real numbers is not bounded. I need to represent a bounded and closed (compact) interval under nonnegative real numbers. It should exclude infinity.

Comment: What do you mean construct?  What is wrong with $[1,2]$?  It is compact and a subset of $\Bbb R_+$.

Comment: @RossMillikan I am looking for a "generic" representation of the largest interval, $[0, b]$ where b can be any finite number .

Comment: The "largest interval" doesn't exist.  Suppose for contradiction that it *did* exist, that you have some $b$ finite such that $m([0,b])$ is maximum (where $m$ represents the standard lebesgue measure).  What can you say about $b+1$?  Since $b$ is finite, $b+1$ is also finite.  However, $m([0,b])=b<b+1=m([0,b+1])$ so $m([0,b])$ is *not* maximum.  Thus, by contradiction, there is no "largest interval".

Comment: @JMoravitz True. I think I made a mistake by saying the largest interval. I want to choose an element from a finite interval under $\mathbb{R_+}$ but I do not know what the upper bound is. How should I write this? Should I just say $x \in [0, b] \subset \mathbb{R_+}$ where b is any finite number ?

Comment: Suppose we have a *finite* (closed) interval $I$ where $I\subset \mathbb{R}_+$.  Since $I$ is an *interval* and is *finite*, we know there must exist some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_+$ with $a<b$ such that $I=[a,b]$.  Picking some $x\in I$ then is picking some $x\in[a,b]$.  **However**, without knowledge of what $I$ is, we cannot *guess* as to what $a$ and $b$ suffice.  Suppose that we were to guess some $a,b$, with $a<b$ without knowledge of what $a$ or $b$ we needed to use.  Then if $I=[b+1,2b+1]$ our guess not only will be wrong, but won't even intersect the true interval.

Comment: The value of $a$ and $b$ is determined by what $I$ is, and we may refer to those values once we have declared the existence of $I$, though we have no further information as to what the exact value of $a$ is or the exact value of $b$ is, as their only definition comes from $I$ itself.

Comment: @JMoravitz In the model that I am trying to construct I know that the element $x$ can take the value $0$ but I just don't know the upper bound and I need a generic representation for that. So $a= 0$ is given.

Comment: "$x\in[0,b]$ **where $b$ is the upper bound**", but as mentioned, if you are going to do any calculations involving $b$, you must know exactly what $b$ is, or must leave it as simply $b$ in the calculations, because you cannot guess a value as it will always have a chance of being wrong.

Comment: @JMoravitz $x$ is used as a symbol throughout my model and no numerical calculations are needed. Thank you for these good comments.